# Implement Rate Limiting in NextJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, throttling

I learned ReactJS and NextJS, but I am having trouble implementing rate-limiting/throttling in NextJS. I want there to be a limit on the number of times the user can access certain requests per period of time.

Comment: With examples from https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares and [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) you can build whatever you want.

Comment: Have you tried throttling the requests using (https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) .

Answer (score 2):

exist and answer for that on the next link.

- looking into whether your serverless database offers any rate-limiting features.
- if you have a reverse proxy available that has rate-limiting features, I'd use that.
- since next.js API routes allow using existing connect middleware, you should be able to rate limit with one of the available rate-limiting middleware

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12134#discussioncomment-6792

And for the last alternative, you can add an express library into a nextjs middleware

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2022-Jul-13**: As of Next.js `v12.2.0`, middleware is now stable.

---

In the latest version of nextjs it is possible through https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware even though it is still in beta.

You can find examples here https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions

Your specific use case examples:

- https://github.com/vercel/examples/blob/main/edge-functions/api-rate-limit-and-tokens
- https://github.com/vercel/examples/blob/main/edge-functions/api-rate-limit