# Implement API Rate Limiting in NextJS deployed on Vercel without Redis

Tags: api, next.js, rate-limiting

I have a public API that can make Create/Read requests to my firebase database.

I have applied cloudflare 'DNS Only' to my domain as Vercel discourages using the proxy mode.

I want to add rate limiting to my APIs but all the examples on the NextJS website are for edge functions and redis, none of which I am using. My website is rather simple.

What's the best way to implement API rate-limiting?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Implement Rate Limiting in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374380/implement-rate-limiting-in-nextjs)?

Comment: @juliomalves no sorry. the answer does not give any way to implement rate limiting in api without redis

Comment: @juliomalves It does. It says "This demo features API Rate limiting at the edge with Redis using Upstash."